# How to create a good print style for Masonry

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

I've made a web page with different items with content which are using the jquery masonry plugin. I want to create a good print style for this page. When printing I want to show a list of this boxes (top to bottom). For these print styles I use the css below. For some reason not all of the items are shown in the printed version, only the first five.

```
@media print {
   #container .item{ display:block !important; float:none !important; 
                     position:relative !important; left:  !important; top:auto !important;  
                     overflow:visible !important; width: 100% !important; 
                     height: 100px !important; clear: left !important;
   }        
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This has worked well for me as a print style on a simple 2 column site using Masonry.

```
.masonry-brick[style]
{
position:relative !important;
display:block !important;
left:0 !important;
top:auto !important;
float:left;
}

#container[style]
{
height:auto !important;
}
```

Comment: Works fine on IE 11, Firefox 47 and Chrome 52 :D

Answer (score 0):

The `left` property is missing a value:

```
left:  !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had Masonry items as `<figure>` containing link `<a>` on image `<img>`.

```
<div id="masonry-container">
  <figure>
    <a>
      <img />
    </a>
  </figure>
  ...
</div>
```

Then I solved like this:

```
  /* 
  Disable Masonry
  based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/13955084
  */

  #masonry-container {
    height:auto !important;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
  }
  .masonry-item {
    position:relative !important;
    left:0 !important;
    top:auto !important;
    float: none !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 3pt;
  }


  /* 
  Set items as inline-block at same height 
  */

  #masonry-container > figure,
  #masonry-container > figure > a,
  #masonry-container > figure > a > img {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 150pt;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 500pt;
  }
```